# Creating a custom bootstrap / bootloader in C#

Tags: deployment, installation, wix, installshield, bootstrapper

We've decided to create a custom bootstrapper for our deployment solution. We are currently re-writing and re-designing our deployment strategy for all of our products. Sadly, none of us are deployment experts.

Here's what we have so far:

A. The MSI packages will be authored in InstallShield. We will use whatever feature Installshield offers (IIS integration, COM registration, Registry, etc). The dialog's created by InstallShield will not be used (that is what the bootstrapper is for). The MSIs will be installed silently.

B. Whenever we need to write CA's for stuff that InstallShield can't handle, we will be writing them in managed code (C#) using DTF. We will be creating a "Custom Action Framework" that will "standardize" how we use custom actions.

C. We will create a custom bootstrapper (the "setup.exe") in C# to "handle" the installation.

We have decided to go with a **multiple MSI approach** and use MSI transaction to "chain" the installation from the boostrapper (inspired from Office 2007 installer)

The boostrapper that we are envisioning to create is inspired from Visual Studio's and SQL Server's bootstrapper. The boostrapper will be responsible for the following:

1. **Prerequisite installation**: Each application require a pre-requisite. These pre-requisites are listed in an XML file placed on the same folder as the MSI (inspired from Office 2007 installer) along with other metadata. Depending on current state of the system, the boostrapper will decide which pre-requisite to be installed or not.
2. **Feature selection**: We are planning to structure the "internal" MSI's feature in such a way that it will not be appropriate to be displayed right away to the end-user. We will have feature labeled as "Core_Files", or "Vista_Only" or "64bit_Only". Depending on the metadata on the XML file (on item 1) and the target system, the bootstrapper will be responsible in "populating" a "feature tree" that the user can customize (also inspired from Office 2007 bootstrapper).
3. **Pre-installation Checks**: The bootstrapper will be responsible in checking if the system is ready to receive the installation. For instance, if a machine needs to reboot prior to installation or if the user needs to manually install a service pack, patch or a windows component. Anything that needs to be done that needs user intervention should be displayed here. Think of it as a check list (a listbox) with checks and exes. (Inspired from SQL server's bootstrapper). The "rules" will be written in C#.
4. **Application Configuration**: For application that needs to be "configured" prior to installation. These "parameters" (user configuration) will be passed to the respective MSI via *MSI Properties*.
5. **Actual Installation**: The bootstrapper will then perform the installation. Proper "transaction" should be observed when necessary. All "products" that should be grouped together shall be displayed as one product in Add/Remove Programs (by messing with the ARP entries). Also, proper progress shall be reported by each MSI being installed.

-- That's what we have so far.

I think there are a couple of out-of-the-box solutions for creating a custom bootstrapper like dotNetInstaller and BMG. We've look into it but it's not as flexible as we've hoped. There's also BURN but we're not sure if it's ready for primetime.

So here we are... we've decided to create our own custom bootstrapper.

Question:

Are we crazy? Shouldn't we be creating our own bootstrapper? Which ideas listed above are not realistic? Is there a better approach?

Any input regarding our situation will be greatly appreciated. Also, if you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, Burn isn't going to be done for at least a year.  You already have InstallShield and IMO it has the best off the shelf bootstrapper currently available.  I'd scope your requirements back and make it fit the box.   Pretty much everything I read from you can be done using InstallShield if you learn to push it to it's limits.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for Burn anyway or some already existing solution.

I'm sure that after some time you'll face new problems that you can't now really imagine. 
If you face them, that means that Burn's developers have already faced them and probably got them solved. If not, Burn has a large community that will fix the potential bug faster than you.

Focus on the software you're developing, not on writing installer/bootstrapper.

If I were in your shoes, I would give a burn a try. I'd get me a couple of days and see if it meets my requirements.