# Chaining MSI in C# and then launching a chained install

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-installer

This question is related to: [Creating a custom bootstrap / bootloader in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711920/creating-a-custom-bootstrap-bootloader-in-c)

I would like to make a chainer in C#. This chainer will chain different MSI and perform a transacted installation.

I've looked into the [TransactedInstaller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.transactedinstaller.aspx) class but I don't think its appropriate.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your question was a little unclear to me so I provided some standard terms.  If you still need help just revise your question a little.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks! I've revised my question. Actually, both the bootstrapper and the chainer will be mixed in a single C# application. The bootstrapper will be used to install not just the Windows Installer but other pre-requisite like the .NET framework.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking:

Bootstrapper:

A program that makes sure Windows Installer is installed.  Originally intended to then call 1 MSI.   But now the bootstrapper can call....

Chainer:

A program that handles the sequencing of various installers ( MSI or legacy )

MSI:

A database that describes the installation requirements of a product.  Recent versions of MSI can chain other MSI's ( but not legacy packages )  but generally still require the use of a bootstrapper to make sure you have the most recent version of MSI.

Bootstrapper and Chainer are used somewhat interchangably.   Some bootstrappers do all execution prior to invoking the MSI and some are more integrated with the MSI providing a robust UI and/or executing packages only if the MSI requires it for your situation.