# Appropriate type of project from Install-shield for multiple installations in single setup

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installshield

Since I'm new to Install-shield, really don't know how to merge multiple installations in single setup file. My project written in C#.
My requirement :

1. If dot-net 3.5 is not installed on system, install 1st and then proceed to step 2.
2. Install setup.exe of python engine.
3. Finally install the project setup.

I tried the "Suite" type project from Install-shield,but it is all very confusing. How should i proceed as per my requirement and what all steps should i take for this type of requirement.

I know only to create basic setup.exe from the project build.

I searched given link..
[Chaining & Bootstrapping multiple MSIs & merging the existing MSIs featureset GUI into a custom one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239861/chaining-bootstrapping-multiple-msis-merging-the-existing-msis-featureset-gu) but still not able get clear information.

Is there any blog similar like this http://blog.iswix.com/2006/11/using-installshield-12-to-install-net.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your application require the related tools to be present on the target machine, the .Net 3.5 and python engine, they must be installed as prerequisites by your installation package. 
So, the "Suite" type project is not the correct approach in this case.

You can start an ordinary installation project type (sorry I'm not very familiar with InstallShield project types) and add the related installation packages(.Net and Python engine) as prerequisites.

Try searching "How to add a prerequisite in InstallShield" in the InstallShield's help file. It should give you a starting point.

Comment: Prerequisites are indeed a fine way to do this, but "dependency" packages in a Suite project serve the same purpose as prerequisites in Basic MSI or InstallScript projects.